# Slow Union All and Left outer join query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to create a resultset based on three different sources (tables):

- reports (540 records)
- business terms (300 records)
- attributes (500k records)

The following SQL works fine:

```
SELECT report.code AS code, report.name AS name, 'report' AS type, report.class AS class 
FROM report
UNION ALL
SELECT businessterm.id AS code, businessterm.business_term AS name, 'business_term' AS type, businessterm.class AS class 
FROM businessterm
UNION ALL
SELECT attributes.table_name AS code, attributes.column_name AS name, 'attributes' AS type, 'P0' AS class
FROM attributes;
```

However, for the attributes-table, the `class`-element must be joined from another table (attributes_class, 600k records).

To my knowledge, the final SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT report.code AS code, report.name AS name, 'report' AS type, report.class AS class 
FROM report
UNION ALL
SELECT businessterm.id AS code, businessterm.business_term AS name, 'business_term' AS type, businessterm.class AS class 
FROM businessterm
UNION ALL
SELECT a.table_name AS code, a.column_name AS name, 'attributes' AS type, a.class AS class
FROM (
    SELECT attributes.table_name, attributes.column_name, attributes_class.class as class
    FROM attributes
    LEFT JOIN attributes_class ON attributes_class.id = attributes.class_id
    ) AS a;
```

When I execute all the separate queries, they run absolutely fine. However, when combined to a single query, it keeps running.

Comment: Hi - your first SQL statement appears to be missing a final FROM clause. In your second SQL statement I’m not sure why you have nested the last SELECT and then just select from it, it doesn’t seem to add anything. If you run just the nested SELECT then does it execute in a reasonable time? If not, please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: In order to help with optimization, we need to know your table definitions as `create table` statements, **their indexes**, and the output of `explain analyze` on your queries (or just `explain` if `explain analyze` won't terminate).

Comment: In your 3rd query, there is no need for a subquery. `select attributes.table_name as code, attributes.column_name as name, 'attributes' as type, attributes_class.class as class from attributes inner join attributes_class on attributes_class.attribute_id = attributes.id`. This likely is not your performance problem, the database *should* optimize it for you, but make sure.

Comment: @NickW you were right, I missed the final FROM-clause in the first SQL. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @Schwern your remark that there was no need for a subquery was correct (the SQL was generated by SQLAlchemy ORM so it was a bit out of my control). However, I manually edited the SQL-statement as per your suggestion, but as you predicted, it did not solve my performance problem. Placing an index did solve it.

Comment: Time each `SELECT` of the Union.  Then, let's see what the issue is with the slowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing the final query with `explain` and `analyze` provided the solution: in table `attributes` it had to create an index for the field that was used in the join-clause (`class_id`).

```
SELECT r.code AS code, r.name AS name, 'report' AS type, r.class AS class 
FROM report r
UNION ALL
SELECT b.id AS code, b.business_term AS name, 'business_term' AS type, b.class AS class 
FROM businessterm b
UNION ALL
SELECT a.table_name AS code, a.column_name AS name, 'attributes' AS type, ac.class AS class
FROM attributes a
LEFT JOIN attributes_class ac ON ac.id = a.class_id;
```